# Network scan without MODIFY_PHONE_STATE privilege

Tags: android, telephonymanager, network-scan

I’m trying to develop an Android APP for mobile network testing on my Samsung A52.
One of the most important task is to perform a network scan to find all the mobile networks available, the signal strength, etc.
Google provides an API for this purpose (TelephonyManager) but the requestNetworkScan method requires MODIFY_PHONE_STATE privilege that is available only for system APPs.
I’m wondering how can APPs like Network Cell Info working if standard APPs can’t have this privilege, are other APIs available?